# Figure window won't appear after issuing show()

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, updates, figure, enthought

I recently updated ipython and pandas to their most recent stable versions. It resulted in some odd behavior in matplotlib where I can't get figures to appear if I run (previously behaving) scripts from the terminal. And if I am in ipython qtconsole I can't get a plot to appear even when issuing the show() command. Unless that is I issue a figure(1) command after issuing a plot command (see pasted code below). My python environment is Enthought's most recent (I believe) installation.

Here is the code/process an a ipython session. No figure appears, until the very last line, which is doesn't seem right.

```
In[1]: figure()
Out[1]: <matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x2f05910>

In[2]: show()

In[3]: plot(arange(10))
Out[3]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x3196b90>]

In[4]: show()

In[5]: draw()

In[6]: figure()
Out[6]: <matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x31a6210>

In[7]: figure(1)
Out[7]:
```

Answer (score 4):

This looks like an issue with the backend you are using. If you are starting `ipython` with the `--pylab` option, you shouldn't need to call `show()` or `draw()`. Try using a different backend (if you have them installed). Some examples:

```
ipython --pylab=tk
ipython --pylab=qt
ipython --pylab=wx
ipython --pylab=gtk
ipython --pylab=osx
```

I suspect that the EPD may only have the tk backend, but I could be wrong.

Comment: EPD should have all of the above (excluding Wx on 64b OS X, and osx/gtk only on appropriate platforms, of course)

Answer (score 1):

I started ipython notebook in the command line with the following command:

```
C:\..\cur_dir> ipython notebook --pylab=inline
```

Then I tried:

```
plot(arange(10))
```

and the image displayed.